# How to excute select query in side store procedure in php mysql if there are multiple rows occurs?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

How to execute `select query` inside **store procedure** in **php mysql** if there multiple rows occur?

first I want to fetch `distinct (chapter_id)` from `a table (practice_test_result)` of specific student

then on behalf of that `distinct(chapter_id )` run one more query for to generate associative array

**The problem I am facing is :**

```
while( row found ){
/* here i perform the SELECT SUM(total_question) - SUM(total_incomplete) , SUM(total_correct) into totalattempt,talcorrect FROM practice_test_summary WHERE student_id =studentid AND chapter_id =chapterid;
set chpapter_successrate[i] =(totalcorrect * 100)/totalattempt; */

}
```

the below code for more about question what exactly i want

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_result//
CREATE PROCEDURE get_result(studentid INT,courseid INT,out chpapter_successrate decimal(10,2))
BEGIN


SELECT distinct(chapter_id)  FROM practice_test_result WHERE course_id =courseid AND student_id =studentid;
set chapterid=chapter_id;
//here i want to use while loop for all chapter_id  and behalf of these chpater id's perform another select statement for performing successrate of specific chapter and store that into an array and return that array as out variable

SELECT SUM(total_question) - SUM(total_incomplete) , SUM(total_correct) into totalattempt,talcorrect FROM practice_test_summary WHERE student_id =studentid AND chapter_id =chapterid;

set chpapter_successrate[i] =(totalcorrect * 100)/totalattempt;


END//
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use to generate your while loop functionality is a mysql "cursor."

You can then "fetch" each chapter_id into a local variable for use in your second select statement.

Here's a link to the mysql documentation and a good example.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

You'll need to modify the above with DECLARE statements for a local chapterid variable.

Also you won't be able to use chpapter_successrate[i] as an array in a MySQL stored procedure. Please see: [How can I simulate an array variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176709/how-can-i-simulate-an-array-variable-in-mysql) for alternatives. Perhaps a temp table would be a good work around.