# Creating array variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am wondering can you create an array variable in MySQL? I know that you can create a normal variable like so `SET @var1 = "myvar";` but is there a way of creating an array? If so how?

Comment: Did you try google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176709/how-can-i-simulate-an-array-variable-in-mysql

Comment: MySQL does not support arrays. Neither in the procedural language nor as a data type.

Answer (score 15):

You can create an array like so

```
SET @arrayVar = 'var1,var2,bar3,foo4';
```

It can be used thus

```
select from myTable where find_in_set(myTable.myColumn, @arrayVar);
```

If you want to create an array from a query, you can use temporary tables

```
create temporary table if not exists tmp_table select myColumn from myTable where
```

Comment: works also on calculated value like : `find_in_set(month(mytable.myDate), @arrayVar)`