# MySQL create string variable

Tags: mysql, variables

Is there any way to use a combination of strings for a MySQL variable?

I know if this is a string of just numbers it isn't a problem, but can I use a SET in this fashion?

```
mysql> select @SQL_BIND_DOCS;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @SQL_BIND_DOCS                                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| '1','2','3','4','5' |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select distinct doc from  documents doc where doc in (@SQL_BIND_DOCS);
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select distinct doc from documents doc where doc in ('1','2','3','4','5');
+---------------------------------+
| doc                             |
+---------------------------------+
| AA                              |
| BB                              |
| CC                              |
| DD                              |
| EE                              |
+---------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

You can see here that there is no issue with the data -- any help provided would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you must to explain what exactly you need.

Comment: I think you need to use a cursor. "User variables are intended to provide data values. They cannot be used directly in an SQL statement as an identifier or as part of an identifier, such as in contexts where a table or database name is expected, or as a reserved word such as SELECT. This is true even if the variable is quoted..."

Comment: Even so, storing what seems to be an array [might be rough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176709/how-can-i-simulate-an-array-variable-in-mysql). I might consider a different data format, such as [a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990392/mysql-select-in-clause-string-comma-delimited) or a [temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35309127/924299). See [Creating array variable in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845503/) and [how to set an array as a mysql user variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424969/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
select distinct doc from  documents doc where FIND_IN_SET(doc, @SQL_BIND_DOCS);
```

In your case, using **IN** does not work, because the variable is [**cast to 1**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4156063/4448410).

**References**

[FIND_IN_SET() vs IN()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in)

[difference between where_in and find_in_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729241/difference-between-where-in-and-find-in-set)

[Why find_in_set works but IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656740/why-find-in-set-works-but-in-clause)