# Split string in MYSQL via CRATE

Tags: mysql, crate, cratedb

I want to split a string in CRATE. I tried with substr, but it takes only substr(string,long,long). I want something like a function which can take delimiter string.

Example :

value=1234-5656

select SUBSTR(value, '-',1) as first from XYZ;

I want to split the value into 1234 and 5656 in a SQL query. But CRATE does not support SUBSTR(value, '-',1). So I am looking for an option to split the value in the CRATE query.

Any help?

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you are asking here.  Please edit your question, and show some sample data, along with whatever SQL you have already tried.

Comment: Hope its clear now.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992575/mysql-substring-extraction-using-delimiter (which is again a duplicate)?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or something else?

Comment: Why don't you use procedure for this issue. I dont think with simple create query you can able to do it.

Comment: Please provide your requirement that what you exactly want to do..

Answer (score 0):

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` comes in handy here:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('1234-5656', '-', 1)  AS first,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('1234-5656', '-', -1) AS second
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please try using this query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '_', 1), '_', -1) as beforesplit, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '_', 2), '_', -1) as aftersplit FROM testenter
```

Answer (score 0):

For CrateDB you probably want to use regex_matches function more info [on Create's documentation site](https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/general/builtins/scalar.html?#regexp-matches-source-pattern-flags)

However the following should give you what you're looking for

```
select regexp_matches(yourColumnName, '([0-9])\w+')[1] from yourTable
```