# Convert T-SQL stored procedure query to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-migration

I am working on convert queries from MS SQL Server  to MySQL

My SQL Server Query is as per below.

```
SELECT      userId,IndustriesID,value AS ProvIndusID
FROM        #Talent_list
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(IndustriesID,',')
```

I am stuck here to convert string to row and cross apply.

[image: Need output as per the this picture]

Comment: Please provide more info on what you're trying to do, sample data and expected result. Read ["How do I ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: That image has nothing to do with your actual SQL query, and why does your code example have the IF statement...

Comment: CROSS APPLY in MySQL https://stackoverflow.com/q/36869221/1690217

Comment: mysql does not have split_string either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992575/mysql-substring-extraction-using-delimiter - and others are out there.

Comment: Do people seriously migrate from MSSQL back to MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have functions that return tables.  You can replace the logic with a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select state, cast(null as char(100)) as city, cities, 0 as lev
      from talent_list
      union all
      select state, substring_index(cities, ',', 1),
             substr(cities, length(substring_index(cities, ',', 1)) + 2), lev + 1
      from cte
      where cities <> '' and lev < 5
     )    
select state, city
from cte
where lev > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9e71ac3e9f3f0d7416a44801a7b1373) is a db<>fiddle.