# query for a value of a field that has multiple values separated by a split |

Tags: mysql

Hello I have an extensive query in mysql I must access a field that has several values, this field is separated by a split, | the resulting value of that field is:

2| Lib|g|500

but I need to get the 500, how can I do it?

```
SELECT
TipoVenta.code Tipo_de_Unidad,


FROM transactions_details 

LEFT JOIN lists as TipoVenta ON catalog_products.salesunit_id = TipoVenta.id

WHERE transactions.contract_id=3 AND transactions.company_id=13 AND  transactions.typeoperation_id =61;
```

I'm trying this query to get the value I need, but how do I include it in my big query? or is there another more effective way?, thanks

``SELECT SUBSTR(CODE, 9, 10)`

Comment: Use the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34993120/18667225)