# Pass string in values of mysql insert query

Tags: mysql

How can i pass string in values rather than passing each value.
Receiving error

Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
  INSERT INTO `ProfileResumeActivityLog`
    (`Email`,`ProfileID`,`ExternalUserDID`, `EventType`, `ResumeDID`, `EventText`, `CreatedOn`)
    VALUES('checkpp@test.com,73443358,XR2Z1WT6WR5PPR6Z99L4,r
 esume_backload,R3W6WN6LFY95PKL27SR,resume_create, NOW()' );
```

I want to pass this as string because my stored procedure takes dynamic number of values for batch insert

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SaveBatchMultipleProfileResumeActivityLog`(
    _resumeBatch            TEXT

)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO `ProfileResumeActivityLog`
    (`Email`,`ProfileID`,`ExternalUserDID`, `EventType`, `ResumeDID`, `EventText`, `CreatedOn`)
    VALUES(_resumeBatch);
    
END
```

**calling**

```
CALL CBAX.SaveBatchMultipleProfileResumeActivityLog   ('checkpp@test.com,73443358,XR2Z1WT6WR5PPR6Z99L4,resume_backload,R3W6WN6LFY95PKL27SR,resume_create, NOW()',

'checkpp@test1.com,73443358,XR2Z1WT6WR5PPR6Z99L41,resume_backload,R3W6WN6LFY95PKL27SR1,resume_create, NOW()' )
```

Comment: You have to add individual string not as a whole. `'checkpp@test.com', 73443358, 'XR2Z1WT6WR5PPR6Z99L4'` and so on.

Comment: i want to use in case multiple values also come @GodWin

Comment: check call to stored proc @Madmax i edited question

Comment: When sending one string, you can split it into different values as is explained here: [MySQL substring extraction using delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992575/mysql-substring-extraction-using-delimiter)

Comment: @Luuk could you please answer how we will do here

Comment: You need a function to do the splitting, there are multiple links in the link I gave you.  Try some of them, it's not hard, and you will gain some experience doing so. At the end you will have a correct working function to solve your problem. (Succes with testing/debugging!)

Answer (score 0):

when you put string inside a insert statement you have to put them inside a "" thats why you get that error.

```
INSERT INTO `ProfileResumeActivityLog`(`Email`,`ProfileID`,`ExternalUserDID`, `EventType`, `ResumeDID`, `EventText`, `CreatedOn`)
VALUES('checkpp@test.com',73443358,'XR2Z1WT6WR5PPR6Z99L4','resume_backload','R3W6WN6LFY95PKL27SR','resume_create', NOW() );
```