# How can I extract second last date from text separated by ; using substring_index in MySQL?

Tags: sql

I get a list of dynamic text which contains multiple dates separated by ;
Need to exact extract second last date/value using substring_index.

Examples of my dynamic text:
First example of my text
`2022-07-01 00:00:00;2022-10-01 00:00:00;2023-01-01 00:00:00;2023-04-01 00:00:00;`

Second example of my text
`2022-07-01 00:00:00;2022-10-01 00:00:00;2023-01-01 00:00:00;2023-04-01 00:00:00;2024-04-01 00:00:00;`

End Result should be from first example = 2023-01-01 00:00:00
End Result should be from Second example = 2023-04-01 00:00:00

My string value are dynamic. Sometimes it contains all together 5 values, sometimes 3 values ... separated by ;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992575/mysql-substring-extraction-using-delimiter

Comment: My string value are dynamic. Sometimes it contains all together 5 values, sometimes 3 values ... separated by ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Substring_Index as the following:

```
set @t='2022-07-01 00:00:00;2022-10-01 00:00:00;2023-01-01 00:00:00;2023-04-01 00:00:00;';
select Substring_Index(Substring_Index(@t, ';', -3), ';', 1) as dt
```

Another option is to use the right and left functions as the following:

```
set @t='2022-07-01 00:00:00;2022-10-01 00:00:00;2023-01-01 00:00:00;2023-04-01 00:00:00;';

select Left(Right(@t, 40), 19);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/kfZ-XO6k)

Comment: Very Smart. Txs.