# Deduplicate Single Cell Mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays, duplicates

I know there is plenty on here about duplicate rows and columns, but I have a single cell (intersection of row and column) that has multiple values that are comma delimited.

This would be somewhat trivial in some scripting language, but I want to keep in MySQL.

I have table checks and the last columns with there are two `val1` values and only one should be returned.

```
+--------+----------+-------------+----------+----------------------------+
| id     | date     | doc         | amount   |  column_with_multiple_vals |
+--------+----------+-------------+----------+----------------------------+
| 346862 | 3/7/2017 | WIRE 111111 | 24651.33 | val1, val2, val3, val1     |
+--------+----------+-------------+----------+----------------------------+
```

Looking around I think this is how it might happen.

1. `Load Data Local Infile`
2. `SET @myArrayOfValues = column_with_multiple_vals`
3. I am a little uncertain of how to go about deduplicating the values in this simulated MySQL array.

I found this ariticle and seemed like it was on the right track of how of what I am looking for.

[How can I simulate an array variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176709/how-can-i-simulate-an-array-variable-in-mysql)

```
SET @myArrayOfValue = '2,5,2,23,6,';

WHILE (LOCATE(',', @myArrayOfValue) > 0)
DO
    SET @value = ELT(1, @myArrayOfValue);
    SET @myArrayOfValue= SUBSTRING(@myArrayOfValue, LOCATE(',',@myArrayOfValue) + 1);

    INSERT INTO `EXEMPLE` VALUES(@value, 'hello');
END WHILE;
```

Comment: Karwin, Bill "SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming", Chapter 2  http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557

Comment: Is it possible for you to put the values of column column_with_multiple_vals values into another table with a foreign key reference to id?

Comment: This is probably an anti-pattern however this is how the data is coming over.  This is just for analytical purpose.  The transaction database/ERP is NetSuite and data structure is not designed in this way.  I can probably re-work and get some other searches, but was hoping this method was possible.