# How to combine multiple queries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, arrays

### Backgronud

I have a DB of restaurants and restaurant chains. In my DB, each restaurant chain has a series of specific restaurants.

For example, the PizzaHut's restaurant chain has  restaurants in my zone.

### Objective

I want to know, given an array of `cityIds`, how many restaurant chains are there. For example, given the array [1, 2] (London and Lisbon), I want to know the ids of the restaurant chains each city has:

```
[
    {cityId: 1, chains: [1, 2, 3]}, 
    {cityId: 2, chains: [4, 5]}
]
```

### Problem

The problem is that I don't know how to do that in a single query. Thus far, I manager to get all the chain ids for a single city:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM   restaurant_chains
       INNER JOIN restaurants
               ON restaurant_chains.id = restaurants.chainId
       WHERE  restaurants.city = MY_CITY_ID_HERE
```

Here I do an `INNER JOIN` between my `restaurant_chains` table and my `restaurants`table `ON` the chain's Id.

Then I go through each restaurant and I check if it is in the city I want.

### Research

The only way to do this for an array of cityIds would be to have an array. But MySQL doesn't have arrays. So I searched and I found `WHILE` loops, `UNION ALL` and `TMP_TABLES`:

[How can I simulate an array variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176709/how-can-i-simulate-an-array-variable-in-mysql)

All of which I honestly don't understand very well and I don't how to apply to my example.

### QUESTION

How to do that single query for an array of cities?

Comment: try using a varaible in mysql. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the city id in addition to everything else you wanted. With that, you can walk through the results and associate each with the city id.

```
SELECT DISTINCT restaurants.city, id
FROM   restaurant_chains
       INNER JOIN restaurants
               ON restaurant_chains.id = restaurants.chainId
       WHERE  restaurants.city IN (CITY_ID1, CITY_ID2, CITY_ID3...)
```