# how to add multiple id in mysql table with same user id?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

I have data like this student_id=1 and class_id=1,2,3 (class id can be multiple) 
  in my controller.

And i want result in mysql table like this:
  [image]

Comment: Make a new middle class/table Student-Class and put the student_id and class_id how attributes, at this table you can save time, signature, etc.. what you need of the class-student

Comment: Are you looking for an asp answer?

Comment: how can i do partition of class_id(1,2,3) using sql statement and insert into table with different rows.Can u help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new middle-table called studentclass with Id being the primary key and Student_Id and Class_Id as foreign keys pointing to their tables. You can then store the Id of studentclass as foreign key in the students table.

Here's an example for better understanding:

Student
Id (Primary)
StudentClass_Id (foreign key)

StudentClass
Id (Primary)
Student_Id (Foreign key)
Class_Id (Foreign key)

Comment: student_id and class_id both are foreign keys from reference table student and class.Now i want to insert multiple class_id with same student id into table with format i have shown in image.

Comment: Then good luck implementing Unnikrishnan Rs answer and consider that your db will be in 2nd normal form.

Comment: can we do partition on class_id(1,2,3) from sql statement and insert into table with different rows?

Comment: how do you mean that? You're maybe looking for this [How can I simulate an array variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176709/how-can-i-simulate-an-array-variable-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You should use any functions like split to make an array from string separated by comma. And you can insert the row in MySQL through looping the array

Comment: It can be done using array and implementing loop but can we do this from mysql statement like seperating class_id(1,2,3) and insert it into table with different rows? If yes then guide me.Thankyou