# MySQL: Can we create an array (associative or not) as a MySQL server script variable?

Tags: mysql, arrays

I've seen a lot of SQL server script variables of this kind: `@variable`. But can we, in fact, store an array (associative or not) behind the `@variable`?

**UPDATE**

This question turns out to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176709/how-can-i-simulate-an-array-variable-in-mysql), which suggests to consider possible using of:

- **SET type** and **JSON type**, which seem to be only column types but not `@variable` types.
- A **TEMPORARY TABLE**, which seem to be stored in HDD (right?).
- Functions working with **JSON strings** (e.g., `JSON_VALUE` and `JSON_LENGTH`), which are usable entirely within MySQL server script. Although, these functions do not help to derive an array and store it in a `@variable` and are merely JSON walkarounds. I would accept this variant but it seems like `@json_string` is parsed each time we call `JSON_VALUE(@json_string)`.

So, till now it seems that there **IS** an opportunity to *CREATE* an array (associative or not!) but there IS **NO** an opportunity to surely *KEEP* the array for its further processing!

Regarding the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176709/how-can-i-simulate-an-array-variable-in-mysql) mentioned in the beginning of this one. Right now I've only reached 5th and 6th answers, which are related to **JSON strings**. They are interesting! Be sure to check them out if you're interested in the subject!

Thanks to everyone for your time!

**UPDATE**

As **@Panagiotis Kanavos** has mentioned, fetching data by value is slower in case of arrays.

But what if:

- We indeed want to simply iterate over *M* input arrays simultaneously and produce *N* output arrays? *(Maybe, we are simply interested in collation of parameters along a timeline and keep the results.)* Arrays are perfectly suitable for this task. But of course, in this case we can still use tables. The question is what will be faster? If our iterative process involves many requests to arrays' elements (can we rely on the server caching the *M* input arrays and that they'll always be at hand?) and creation of multiple result arrays (how long will it take in case of tables and how do we know that tables are created in RAM for fast access?)?
- We want to create an array manually along the course of a server script and are going to only use it in C-like style (aren't going to fetch its data by value) and after the script execution there'll be no need in the array? So, this will be a classic C-like script-only array. To me, in this case putting the array directly into the RAM is what we need and will be more effective than table creation (which'll probably go to HDD), won't it?

And so, the 2nd (and more general) question arises: *How far can we rely on the server's optimizations?*

I understand that a huge work's been put in optimization in many ways. But has somebody met a situation when a server didn't optimize in the best way? When a programmer had to explicitly rearrange the code in order to manually bring it to the optimal state?

Comment: What do you mean array? json array?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have arrays. Why do you wan them? As for `@variable`, are you sure that's array syntax or even MySQL syntax? `@variable` are SQL Server script variables and parameter names

Comment: @D-Shih I mean any group of items accessible by an index (not necessarily numeric, actually). Thank you for your fast reply.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos session variables are defined as `@variable_name` in mysql

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as Shadow has mentioned, I was indeed talking about server script `@variables` a.k.a. session `@variables`. There is a quite new JSON type for table columns but it seems to be inapplicable to `@variables` we are talking about.

Comment: @Daniil why do you need this in the first place? Relational databases work with tables. The query engine can use indexes and statistics to execute queries far faster than any hand-rolled loop or brute-force search in memory. After all, the database server *already* caches data and indexes. Trying to second-guess the database will typically result in far slower code (orders of magnitude) and concurrency blocks. All those session variables you mention steal memory away from data caches and indexes and hint at attempts to pass data between functions or stored procedures from the back door

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's true but still it seems like when directly accessed, a session array in RAM will work faster than a table (which, I assume, can be stored either in RAM or in HDD, subjects to situation). Is it not correct? Or can we be sure that when we call `JSON_VALUE(@object_json_string, @property)` the server will keep the parsed `object` in the RAM?

Comment: Only if you ignore the time taken to load the data into the array, and the array is so small it doesn't matter anyway. Is an array  faster than a dictionary? Yes, if it's only a few items. Using an array means you can't JOIN data, only iterate over them, which is the slowest way possible. What is faster, set operations between two HashSet objects, or set operations between two arrays that require nested loops?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, data load will take time. But what if we need to create an array manually specially for this server script and are going to use the array in pure C-like style? Please, see the *UPDATE*!

Comment: A `TEMPORARY TABLE` goes away when the connection is closed (or otherwise dies).  A regular `TABLE` is permanent.  `ENGINE=MEMORY` goes away when the machine is shutdown.

Comment: Iterating over an array is likely to be very slow.  Using the power of SQL to perform an operation to every row in a table 'simultaneously' is how you should design things.

Comment: @RickJames Do you mean that `TEMPORARY TABLE` is stored in RAM?

Comment: @RickJames According to all the comments, it seems like we can rely on MySQL optimization entirely. Even in case of array-like `TABLE`s and probably even in case of multiple parsing of JSON strings by `JSON_VALUE(...)`. Maybe, we should think like: 1) If arrays would be more efficient then they would be provided. 2) If parsed JSON arrays wouldn't be stored in RAM when necessary then there ould be provided an opportunity to manually handle their RAM storage.

Comment: @RickJames could you, please, share how you would solve the following task: creation several identical tables with different names and fill them with the same content? E.g., each table can be an initial statistics of a fresh app user (and now you have multiple users to deal with). Of course, you can create a single table and put all users' statistics into the one but the thing is that you need to track it hour by hour, so such a single table would become tremendously large.

Comment: @Daniil - `CREATE TABLE T_123 LIKE T_template;  INSERT INTO T_123 SELECT * FROM T_template;`

Comment: @RickJames Bright and clear! Thank you!