# JSON_VALUE and path as variable in MySQL 8.x not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I use Mysql 8.0 and trying to use JSON_VALUE to work with arrays in stored procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `tJS` ()
BEGIN
   DECLARE _counter INT DEFAULT 0;
   SET @arr = '["123","3","15"]';

   WHILE _counter < JSON_LENGTH(@arr) DO
     --here I want extract element with index _counter from @arr 
     SET @ix = CONCAT('$[', _counter, ']') ;
     SET @v = JSON_VALUE(@arr, @ix);
     -- some stuff with @v must be here
   END WHILE;
END
```

I get error at line SET @v = JSON_VALUE(@arr, @ix):

*"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@ix);"*

As I found out, in MySQL 8 JSON_VALUE works only if path(second parameter) a fixed string, not variable.

So, this command works:

```
SET @v = JSON_VALUE(@arr, '$[0]')
```

And this command throws sames yntax error:

```
SET @v = JSON_VALUE(@arr, CONCAT('$[', _counter, ']'));
```

Is there any way in MySQL 8.0 to set second parameter in JSON_VALUE not fixed string, but variable?

Comment: This looks like the very definition of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Explain what you're actually trying to do. That is, whatever's covered by the `-- some stuff with @v must be here` comment. I'll guess that there is a better way than using an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-value says:

> `path` is a JSON path pointing to a location in the document. This must be a string literal value.

So the answer is no, you can't use a variable in place of the path.

You can use [PREPARE and EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) to run a dynamic SQL query, after concatenating your path expression into the SQL query string before it is prepared.

But my opinion is that your approach is inadvisable for several reasons:

- Using an expression or variable for the JSON path when the manual says it doesn't support this (you should have checked the doc for JSON_VALUE() before posting to Stack Overflow).
- Using a JSON document when you really want to use SQL expressions to process discrete elements within that document as if they are relational data (JSON is not relational).
- Using a MySQL stored procedure for a task that would be easy in literally any other programming language.

Comment: Thanks, I should have read the documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example to get the first item from a JSON array:

```sql
SET @counter = 0;
SET @json_doc = '["foo", "bar", "baz"]';
SET @json_path = CONCAT('$[', @counter, ']');
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@json_doc, @json_path));
```

Here's a longer example that creates a test table and inserts three values from a JSON array.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (`item` VARCHAR(3));

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_procedure`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE _counter INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET @json_doc = '["foo", "bar", "baz"]';

    WHILE _counter < JSON_LENGTH(@json_doc) DO
        SET @json_path = CONCAT('$[', _counter, ']');
        SET @json_value = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@json_doc, @json_path));
        
        SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO `test_table` (`item`) VALUES ("replace_value")';
        SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, "replace_value", @json_value);

        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        SET _counter = _counter + 1;
    END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL `test_procedure`();
DROP PROCEDURE `test_procedure`;

SELECT * FROM `test_table`;
DROP TABLE `test_table`;
```