# Error with mysql JDBC driver for method createArrayOf

Tags: java, mysql, database, sqlite, jdbc

I'm a begginer java programmer. In my dummy projects I'm  using the mysql JDBC 5.17 driver for connect to my database

Today I have a simply query

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE idb IN (?)
```

I have this Array of int:

```
int[2] idBooks = new int{1,2};
```

and I would to select the books with the id in idBooks

When I use the API "createArrayOf" the JVM throws on the console this error:

```
  java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
```

I know that my driver not support the "createArrayOf" method, there are other solution for do that?

I hope my question is not trivial :)

Thanks a lot in advance, sorry for my english Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

**Java**:

```
// str_idBooks will be [1, 2]
String str_idBooks = Arrays.toString( idBooks );
```

You have to replace `'['`, `' '`(spaces), `']'` from the string to pass to MySQL query.

**MySQL**:

If you did not replace the characters as said above, use this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM books
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET( idb, 
                    replace(replace(replace(?,'[',''),']',''),' ','')
                  ) > 0
```

If you have replaced the characters as said above, use this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM books
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET( idb, ? ) > 0
```

Use the Prepared Statement to set the parameter as :

```
pst.setString( 1, str_idBooks );
```

Answer (score 1):

It [seems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLFeatureNotSupportedException.html) that MySQL doesn't have array variables.May 
U can try temporary tables instead of array variables

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_temp_table
SELECT * FROM people WHERE last_name = 'John';
```

Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433978/array-variable-in-mysql).

Comment: How will be my query in my case with some ids?

Comment: If you are using id you try 'IN'. Refer this you should get some idea.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476146/mysql-php-select-where-id-array

Comment: @AndreaCatania here is an example using temp table for keeping ids to other queries. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71799005/1864883