# Retrive ids of ResultSet and return as java.sql.Array

Tags: mysql, scala, prepared-statement

I have the follow:

```scala
  def getIds(name: String): java.sql.Array = {
    val ids: Array[Integer] = Array()
    val ps: PreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = ?")
    ps.setString(1, name)
    val resultSet = ps.executeQuery()
    while(resultSet.next()) {
      val currentId = resultSet.getInt(1)
      ids :+ currentId
    }
    return connection.createArrayOf("INTEGER", ids.toArray)
  }
```

My intention is to use this method output to put into another PreparedStatement using `.setArray(1, <array>)`

But I'm getting the follow error: `java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`

I'm using MySQL. Already tried INTEGER, INT, BIGINT. No success with none of then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researching more found this:

> [It seems that MySQL doesn't have array variables. May U can try temporary tables instead of array variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22067080/1864883)

So my solution was to create a temp table with just ids:

```scala
val idsStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
   "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE to_delete_ids SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = ?")
idsStatement.setString(1, name)
idsStatement.executeUpdate()
```

Than do inner join with other statments/queries to achieve same result:

```scala
val statementDeleteUsingIds = connection.prepareStatement(
    "DELETE to_delete_rows FROM table2 to_delete_rows INNER JOIN to_delete_ids tdi ON tdi.id = to_delete_rows.other_tables_id")
statementDeleteUsingIds.executeUpdate()
```